# Run R in Jupyter notebook - kernel is dying

Tags: jupyter-irkernel

I am attempting to run R in Jupyter notebook. I tried almost everything what I have found, but without results. So I tried to reinstall Anaconda (Python 2.7.13, Anaconda 4.3.0, IPython 5.1.0) and R (version 3.3.2) to have the latest versions.

Afterwards, I ran

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

But If I open Jupyter notebook and create a new file with R kernel, the kernel dies immediately and I get long error, see the full version [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17NQ0LW0b3O2P1OLnN_DND3nOeRKuemZGsUTXovNKu5E). The last line:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any suggestions will be very appreciated.